# Allowing only one active state across multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, button

I am trying to have 3 buttons that toggle their active state based on if the others are clicked.

 So if button 1 is active, button 2 and 3 should not be. My buttons are arranged in the following way.

```
<ButtonClickable3  name="Medium" value="10" onClick={(event) => addPizza(event)}></ButtonClickable3>
<ButtonClickable3 name="Large" value="15" onClick={(event) => addPizza(event)}></ButtonClickable3>
<ButtonClickable3 name="Extra Large" value="20" onClick={(event) => addPizza(event)}></ButtonClickable3>
```

And the component is this

```
const ButtonClickable3 = (props) => {
    const [isActive, setActive] = useState("false");
    const handleToggle = (e) => {
     setActive(!isActive);
     props.onClick(e)
     
    }; 
     return <button
               type="button"
               value={props.value}
               name={props.name}
               className={isActive ? "button btn fourth" : "button btn fourthActive"}
               onClick={handleToggle}
             >
              {props.name}
             </button>
   
   }
```

Currently the only thing I can accomplish is having all the buttons turn on and off together. I.E. One is clicked and they all change active state.

How am I able to make only one be active at a time?

I have put my code in a codesanbox

[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-perlman-pqln8?file=/src/CYO.js)
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I dont see the issue in your posted codesandbox

Comment: If there are three buttons and only one can be selected at a time, using radio buttons is preferred (and easier to make it accessible).

Comment: @EugenSunic I think the problem is that if you select button 1 and then 3 for example, button 1 still has the active color. You can also select and deselect a size. I agree with what ZsoltMeszaros said, radio buttons would make more sense for a functionality like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state for the buttons needs to be moved from the ButtonClickable3 component up to the parent.

So you would have something like

```
const [selectedPizzaSize, setSelectedPizzaSize] = useState()
```

Then pass in a `selected` prop to the components themselves

```
<ButtonClickable3 name="Medium" value="10" selected={selectedPizzaSize === "10"} onClick={(event) => addPizza(event)}></ButtonClickable3>
<ButtonClickable3 name="Large" value="15" selected={selectedPizzaSize === "15"} onClick={(event) => addPizza(event)}></ButtonClickable3>
<ButtonClickable3 name="Extra Large" value="20" selected={selectedPizzaSize === "20"} onClick={(event) => addPizza(event)}></ButtonClickable3>
```

You'll need to call `setSelectedPizzaSize` inside your `addPizza` function